# Failed to deploy spring boot app on heroku

Tags: spring, heroku

I'm trying to deploy spring boot app on heroku, but its giving this error.

> Executing: ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install /app/tmp/buildpacks/e782c3288b01b248be381c97e3f23aeda5e610f7dd2f2c9749a89a771b32043a84f622fb4ec83d116e950b751bc6916ba9aae8b55677a38a1b21c9dd14ed5ecb/lib/maven.sh:
> ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>
> !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please follow below steps in order to deploy web application in heroku.

Change the packaging to war. 
`<packaging>war</packaging>`
Right click your project select `RunAs -> Maven Install`, once maven cleans and build the project under target folder you project war will be created. Rename if you want it.

I hope you download `heroku cli`. If not click [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#windows) and install.

Now Open cmd and login to heroku using these [command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#getting-started), once logged in successfully then navigate to the `war created location`(target location of your project) using `cd` command.

Install [heroku-cli-deploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-cli) plugin. Once installed execute the below command `heroku war:deploy <war_file_name.war> --app <app_name>` app_name will be the project your created in heroku.
 Once war uploaded successfully, execute the below command in order to start the application `heroku ps:scale web=1`.